# Find if Employee is a manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables `employee` and `employeeManager`.

`Employee` table has 3 columns:

```
employeeId (pk), firstname, lastname
```

`EmployeeManager` table has 5 columns:

```
employeemanagerid (PK), 
employeeid (FK references employee > employeeid), 
managerid  (FK references employee > employee id), 
effectivestartdate,
effectiveenddate
```

I need to display records as

```
Employeeid, firstname, lastname, isManager
```

The `IsManager` column can have 2 values: `Y` for yes and `N` for no.

I need to find the status as of today. I.E. On the day query is run.

Any help?

Comment: What have you already tied and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you have a rule that says that a manager has people reporting to him or her.  That is not the case in the real world, but it is necessary for answering your question.

You basically want an `exists` clause to see if anyone exists who is reporting to the manager.  That looks like:

```
select e.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from employeemanager m
                          where m.managerid = e.employeeid and
                                m.effectivestartdate <= getdate() and
                                m.effectiveenddate > getdate()
                         )
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as isManager
from employee e;
```

Answer (score 1):

This subquery:

```
select distinct managerid
from employeemanager
where convert(date, getdate()) between effectivestartdate and effectiveenddate
```

returns all the managers.
Left join the table `employee` to that subquery and with a CASE expression get the results you need:

```
select e.*, 
  case when t.managerid is null then 'N' else 'Y' end isManager
from employee e left join (
  select distinct managerid
  from employeemanager
  where convert(date, getdate()) between effectivestartdate and effectiveenddate 
) t on t.managerid = e.employeeid
```